# Boostrap Nav Bar with multiple pages - non href anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So here is some code I'm working with.
I wanted to use a bootstrap nav bar but I have tried it with `data-toggle="tab"` but this seems to only work when the `hrefs` are `anchors` and not `urls`.

Is there any best practices to get this to work?

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li id="exchangesHeader">
           <a href="exchanges/overview">Exchange Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li id="companiesHeader">
           <a href="companies/all">All Companies</a>
      </li>
      <li id="usersHeader">
           <a href="users/all">All Users</a>
      </li>
      <li id="optionsHeader">
           <a href="options/basic">Basic</a>
</ul>
```

I want the page that you are viewing, correlated to a highlighted tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly is `data-toggle="tab"` in your code? Show the HTML for the contents too.

Comment: This was about as much as I can show, I'm an intern so i only have access to certain files

Comment: Are you trying to load tab content that is on the page that you are viewing or pull content from a different page and load it?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit wonky. `<a>` tags *are* anchors. They cannot have anchors as atributes. I suspect that you mean "ID selector href attributes" instead.

Comment: its logical actually that it isn't working. Tabs are made for in-page navigation, while you try to go off page. The anchors refer to the specific div that needs to be loaded when selecting a tab. So yea, this isn't working in your way. What you can do is simulate this effect with a bit of css to make it "appear" that tab (in this case then the page) is active.